# How To Handle User Login/Registration?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, user-accounts

I have an iPhone app that uses core data.  I want to add account management to this app for backup and social reasons.  What is the easiest way to handle account registration and login?  Will I need to create a PHP script or create an XML/JSON file?

Any advice would be great.  I have no idea what to do (I'm only familiar with Cocoa Touch).

Edit:

I think I will be going with a twitter login.  Hmm, so if I do a twitter login, when the user signs in, their account data will be loaded into my database? Or something similar? I think I still need my own server because if a user signs in from another device, their data should show up there too.

Answer (score 1):

From a usability standpoint, it would be best to use login's from [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/) or [Twitter](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine) as the user will generally prefer to have a single login. They make sdk's for this, and it also reduces the amount of work you have to do on your end to maintain accounts. If the account is essential to your app then explore other options, but if it is just social, as you mentioned above, don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Might also want to look into game-center.

Comment: Yes, I've been looking into that and have decided to go with a twitter login and am somewhat familiar with their API.  But I'm still confused as to how it all works together.  So will my data still be stored on my device, right?  Like lets say the user logs in via twitter, then does that let me see all their account info? And their friends etc?  I want to implement a follow/following
 feature similar to Instagram, FoodSpotter, Dribbble, etc.

Comment: This seems to be under the scope of a different question. I would suggest giving it a go, then posting specific questions about its implementation here. For now, read up on this: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/sign_in_with_twitter

Comment: Thanks, so I know how the sign in works, it can get your data etc.  But how is the twitter data tied to the data in my core data model?  Do I still need an online database?

Comment: It all depends on what you are trying to do… I know nothing of your business model or app. If you are routing all social aspects through your server, then perhaps, but this really is entirely dependent on your individual setup. I am sorry but I have no easy answer for you.

Comment: Hmm, so if I do a twitter login, when the user signs in, their account data will be loaded into my database? Or something similar?  I think I still need my own server because if a user signs in from another device, their data should show up there too.